# Comment Blacklist

Tags: comments, options, moderation

I have a list of words that I placed in my blacklist_key option values `update_option( 'blacklist_keys', $words);`. But I still can make a comment with such words. Any ideas?

I can't answer my question yet, so here it is. There is no clean way to do this. You have to use a multiline string such that:

```
$words = 'word1
          word2
          word3';
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test and the comment blacklist appears to be ignored for logged in administrators (possibly other roles). It does effectively block comments when logged in as a subscriber. I suspect that that is the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: No I was able to see them as a subscriber. Now I was just reading [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) and I realized that my variable `$words` is an array of strings not a string. Im gonna change this, hopefully it will work.